# CS50 Pset 4 Blur | Invalide operands to binary expression

Tags: cs50, operands

*Currently working on the blur function for the Pset4 of CS50*

It is a lot of text and probably not the most optimal way of doing things but I am not worried about that right now.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    
    // Set blur as a RGBTRIPLE 
    RGBTRIPLE blur[1][1];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Check for corner or edge
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) // If top left corner
            {
                blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4;
                blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4;
                blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4;
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == (width - 1)) // If top right corner
            {
                blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4;
                blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4;
                blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4;
            }
            else if (i == (height - 1) && j == 0) // If bottom left corner
            {
                blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4;
                blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4;
                blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4;
            }
            else if (i == (height - 1) && j == (width - 1)) // If bottom right corner
            {
                blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4;
                blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4;
                blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4;
            }
            else if (i == 0) // If top edge
            {
                blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
                blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
                blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j] + image[i + 1][j + 1]) / 6;
            }
            else if (j == 0) // If left edge
            {
                blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
                blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
                blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j] + image[i - 1][j + 1]) / 6;
            }
            else if (i == (height - 1)) // If bottom edge
            {
                blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
                blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
                blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j] + image[i][j + 1]) / 6;
            }
            else if (j == (width - 1)) // If right edge
            {
                blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 6;
                blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 6;
                blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j] + image[i - 1][j - 1]) / 6;
            }
            else
            {
            // Calculate blur value for each RGB
            blur[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
            image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + 
            image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 9;
            
            blur[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
            image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + 
            image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 9;
            
            blur[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed +
            image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + 
            image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 9;
            
            // Change each RGB value of pixel to blur value
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blur[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = blur[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = blur[i][j].rgbtRed;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

when I compile I get this :

```
**helpers.c:104:141: error: invalid operands to binary
      expression ('int' and 'RGBTRIPLE')
  ...image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j]...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**
```

It only shows this for the **rgbtRed** values when I am checking the edges

I'm very confused because it compiles fine if I get rid of the statements that checks for edges. Even the ones that check for corners work fine.

If you guys know what's up please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j] + image[i][j + 1]) / 6;
```

I believe you forgot to put `.rgbtRed` 's in the last lines of your 4 edge checks.

Comment: omg I didn't even think of checking that. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I recently finished the cs50 psets, so all the errors I had are still fresh in my mind haha.